# Thread through functions unless not null

Tags: clojure

Is there a built in macro for that?

```
(defn keep-looking-for-value-in-multiple-sources [value source1 source2 ...]
  (let [ ret (source1 value)]
       (if ret
         ret
         (let [ret (source2 value)]
           (if ret
             ret
             (...))))
       )
  )
```

I know it's easy to implement a macro, but maybe there is a idiomatic approach?

Comment: Please specify your question further and tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on whether you can live with `false` being treated equally to `nil` (as your example suggests), you could just use `or`:

```
(or (source1 value)
    (source2 value)
    ...)
```

This should not be unreasonably verbose in most cases, but obviously only works if you know (and explicitly use) the collection of functions you want to apply.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've come up with

```
(some #(% value) [source1 source2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a macro. The function you specify is roughly [as you have it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27079168/1562315), with a suitable frame:

```
(defn keep-looking-for-value-in-multiple-sources [value & sources]
  (some #(% value) sources))
```

But is this really what you want? For example,

```
(keep-looking-for-value-in-multiple-sources -2 pos? odd? even?)
;true
```

... not very informative.

I blame [`some`](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/some/). For example, if I write

```
(some odd? (range))
```

... I intuitively expect `1`. In fact, I get `true`, the first truthy result of applying `odd?` to successive elements of `(range)`. There is no standard function that does what, IMO, `some` ought to do.

Comment: Yes! :) I find myself writing code like `(some #(if (test? x) x false) coll)` all the time. I also wish that `(some coll)` defaulted to `(some identity coll)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
user> (defn keep-looking [value & sources]
        (loop [s sources]
          (if-let [ret ((first s) value)]
            ret
            (recur (rest sources)))))
#'user/keep-looking
user> (keep-looking :something 
                    {:not-something 1}
                    {:something 3})
;=> 3
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if no match is found (because `(first s)` will be `nil`).

Comment: Correct. The code was written this way to reflect the example code in the question.